# Redux: useSelector is not updating the state after useDispatch

Tags: javascript, react-redux

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';    

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const settingState = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.setting);

const _onEmailEdit = (value: string) => {
     dispatch(updateField('email', value.trim()));
}

<TextInput
      placeholder="Enter Email"
      keyboardType="email-address"
      textContentType="emailAddress"
      autoCompleteType="email"
      autoCapitalize={'none'}
      value={settingState.userDetails.email || ''}
      onChangeText={_onEmailEdit}
      autoFocus
    />
```

And the dispatch functions ...

```
export const updateField = (
    fieldName: Setting.UpdatableFieldName,
    value: string,
) => ({
    type: Setting.UPDATE_FIELD,
    payload: {
        fieldName,
        value,
   },
});




  return {
    ...state,
    userDetails: {
      ...state.userDetails,
      [fieldName]: value,
    },
    errorMessage: '',
  };
```

TextInput is changing on the screen but when I close and reopen screen then, useSelector value is the same.

How can I set state using dispatch? Thanks.

Comment: can you show us the `updateField` function and the complete code of your reducer. What do you mean by `when I close and reopen screen then, useSelector value is the same` ?

Comment: export const updateField = (
  fieldName: Setting.UpdatableFieldName,
  value: string,
) => ({
  type: Setting.UPDATE_FIELD,
  payload: {
    fieldName,
    value,
  },
});

I want to save state using useDispatch for all over the screens like global.

Is it possible?

Comment: yes, in redux the store is global to your app so this would be already the case. Your code seems to be ok. Are you sure you are not resetting the state before goring to another screen ?